# Does emacs lisp support lexically redefining a function?

Tags: function, emacs, elisp, lexical-scope

Recent versions of Emacs support lexical binding for variables in elisp code. Is it also possible to lexically redefine functions? In other words, does Emacs Lisp have something like `lexical-flet`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Emacs<24.3, you can `(require 'cl)` and then use `labels`.  In Emacs-24.3 and up, you can also do `(require 'cl-lib)` and then use either `cl-flet` or `cl-labels`.

All of those are "complex macros" that generate code that looks like `(let ((fun (lambda (args) (body)))) ... (funcall fun my-args) ...)`, because the underlying language does not natively support local function definitions.

Comment: I'm switching to this as the accepted answer, since it is more complete and gives the full background.

Answer (score 2):

There is `labels` but I don't know if that's what you're looking for:

```
(defun foo ()
  42)

(defun bar ()
  (foo))

(list
 (foo)
 (bar)
 (labels ((foo ()
               12))
   (list (foo)
         (bar)))
 (foo)
 (bar))
```

It returns `(42 42 (12 42) 42 42)`.

Comment: To me 24.2.1 returns "Symbol's function definition is void: labels"

Comment: `(require 'cl)`. If you have a recent enough version, use `(cl-labels ...)` instead.

Comment: The docstring says "This is like `flet`, except the bindings are lexical". That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!